# Can't play audio from Debian 12 RC

Tags: debian, audio, usb-audio

I have a self-built PC consisting of a Gigabyte Z590i Vision D motherboard that I used to run Zorin on. It was great, but I now have a need to use Proxmox so I wanted to switch to Debian.  I'm going to run a desktop on top of the proxmox system since I am using it also as a desktop. It might not be an ideal scenario, but I am limited to a single PC right now I am working on this ready for when Debian 12 is officially released in June, when I play a clean install.

When I was running Zorin, out of the box, everything worked. Since installing Debian I had to add lots of repo's to get things working, but the last thing is the sound which I just cannot figure out the issue for.

In settings I see `Digital Output (S/PDIF) - USB Audio` as the only audio device but the speakers are plugged into a 3.5mm jack. I don't have and S/PDIF port as far as I can see, and the USB hub I use for connecting a monitor doesn't either.

It looks like audio should work, but I have no idea where from. I can also use my USB-C to 3.5mm jack mobile phone adapter, but I see that more as a workaround rather than a solution.

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Audio [USB Audio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I've toyed with just going back to Zorin or Ubuntu 23.04 but then I cannot run Proxmox. My main reason for using Proxmox as a VM host was that its managed through a browser meaning I can use my work laptop or my iPad to manage it easily (as well as gaining experience with it). Is there a web based alternative to Proxmox that would run on Ubuntu perhaps?